# Create a expandable fab to custom dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, floating-action-button

I would like to create a fab to custom dialog animation and transition , i tried many codes and libraries but the outcome is not as i expected it to be , so i want to basically click the fab and overtime it shapes into a custom view or custom dialog as shown below , Thank you

- Youtube Url

[Youtube Link Here](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vXl3lSZzDDg)

Answer (score 0):

```
fab.setOnClickListener {
// Create an ObjectAnimator that scales the FAB from its current size to the size of your custom view or dialog.
val scaleAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
    fab,
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1.0f, 0.0f),
    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1.0f, 0.0f)
)
scaleAnimation.duration = 500 // set the duration of the animation in milliseconds

// Set a listener to be notified when the animation is complete.
scaleAnimation.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
        // Once the animation is complete, remove the FAB from the view hierarchy.
        fab.visibility = View.GONE

        // Show your custom view or dialog on top of the FAB.
        val customView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null)
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.setContentView(customView)
        dialog.show()
    }
})

// Start the animation.
scaleAnimation.start()
}
```

Comment: Thank you , this animation is good but not exactly what i want  , what i want is like while animating , it shapes that fab which is circular to rectangle which dialog view

Comment: PLEASE SENDMA DEMO VIDEO

Comment: @Taki correct, How did you achieved it then ?